# How to refer brcypt encoder to customized authentication provider?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring project, I have defined my own custom authentication provider. Before bringing in Spring Security, I used BCrypt in Java code and now passwords are saved after BCrypting in Database.

spring-security.xml

```
 <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
            </security:authentication-provider> 
       </security:authentication-manager> 

    <b:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <b:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.cT.www.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </b:bean>
```

And my custom authentication provider looks as follows.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        super();
    }


    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;    

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println(authentication.getName() + "principal" +(String) authentication.getCredentials() );

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        UserSignUp user = (UserSignUp) personService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null || !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
        }

        if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
        }

        List<Role> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

I don't wanna use `user-service-ref` in spring-security.xml wihtin authentication-manager.

Answer (score 1):

If your user passwords are already saved as BCrypt in database you don't need much of thing to do. In your authenticate method just replace your password checking condition with below

```
    if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.getPassword())) {
       throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
    }
```

Refer [BCrypt](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html) source for more details.

Comment: Ok. The other issue that I am facing is  @Override
 public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
   throws AuthenticationException {
  authentication.getCredentials() returns "" but authentication.getName() returns the username entered by user in the login form.

Comment: it might be that `password-parameter` is not matching on your password field on login form. Also if the answer is correct and your main problem is solved please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to BCryptPasswordEncoder this way:

```
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="encoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
  </beans:bean>
```

For details see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/

Comment: I get this org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot have child elements when used with 'ref' attribute  . Also I want to ref to my custom authentication provider as well.